# Find All References To Child Method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I want to find all calls to `DateTime.ToString` references in my assembly. In Visual Studio you can "Find All References" by right clicking on `ToString`; however, that returns all references to `ToString` for all classes and not just `DateTime`.

A regular search for `DateTime.ToString` won't work because of the following example:

```
DateTime myDate = new DateTime();
myDate.ToString();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: @Sajeetharan How would that help? That would give every call to "ToString" not just within DateTime. Can you explain?

Comment: How about a FindAll on "DateTime.ToString", or do you want it on any instance of DateTime. That would be much harder.

Comment: That wouldn't work for "DateTime myDate =...." Next Line. "myDate.ToString()"

Comment: Good question then, this is kind of tricky...

Comment: If you use resharper, there is a 'Find Usages Advanced' that kind of works.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use ReSharper for that.

Steps:

1. [Download and install ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/) (trial version will work for you)
2. Open your project/solution in Visual Studio
3. Find usage of ToString(), like `myDate.ToString();`
4. Right click on `ToString` token
5. Select `Find Usages Advanced ...` menu item
6. Tick the appropriate boxes in window as on screenshot below and click `Find`
7. PROFIT

[image]

Comment: ReSharper probably pays Microsoft to don't implement this BASIC feature. So they can still exist.

Answer (score 9):

In VS2015 when you try to Find References for override method, you have them grouped by type in 

Results like this:
[Find Symbol Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn0n2.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Visual Studio 2019, right-click on the desired method name, and then click "View Call Hierarchy."  A "Call Hierarchy" window appears at the bottom (by default) of Visual Studio.  In the left pane, you'll see a tree representation of the projects that call the method.  Within each project, the first item is "Calls To [MethodName]."  Expand this first item for a list of methods.  Clicking each method will change the right pane of the "Call Hierarchy" window to show the lines where the method is called.  Double-click these lines to go to them and address them individually.

Comment: Hi - did you manage to get specific ToString calls for A SPECIFIC ENUM? i see it destinguished between "System.Enum" "toString" and its base - System.ValueType.tostring...

Answer (score 1):

In visual studio, AFAIK it is not possible, though resharper can.

In resharper, Find Advanced Usages window you can filter out which type you're looking for. You can specify less derived or more derived.

So in this case, you can filter out only `DateTime`, or all `ValueType` or `System.Object`.

[image]

---

In this case I guess visual studio can't help, still I'd like to share some tricks.

For example: If you want to find all references of `PropertyChanged` event of your `Person` class assuming person implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, You are going to get tons of references as there are numerous classes which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

What you can do about it is, just go to `Person` class and comment out the implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Then Find all references in visual studio will tell you only the references of `Person` class. Not all types.

At least I hope this trick can help in some other place if not now.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial tool [NDepends](http://www.ndepend.com/) is really good for that: it lets you find what assemblies / classes / methods use a particular one.

It may not be cheap, but if you have a large code base -especialy with several assemblies- it can be very effective!